# Can we call final field as object's constant?

Tags: java, object-oriented

We call `static final` fields as `constant`, rather I should say `Class constant`.
So can we call just `final` fields as `Object's constant`? Is it right to say this?

```
Edited ::
```

Consider the following code :

```
class JustFinal
{
    final int a=20;
    final int b;

    JustFinal(int x, int y){
        //a=x;
        b=y;
    }

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        JustFinal jf = new JustFinal(100,200);
    }
}
```

In the above code field `a` will have a same value for all the object instances and field `b` can have a different value for a different object instance. Shouldn't we call the `final field a` as `CONSTANT` and `final field b` as `OBJECT's CONSTANT`?

Comment: I think you're talking about final fields (or members), not variables; "Variables" usually refers to variables inside a method (Which can also be final).

Comment: @aviv : Thanks for the correction. I have made an edit for the same in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any value that is determined at compile time and is unable to be changed can be considered a *[constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_%28computer_science%29)*.

In your example code, you shouldn't be using `final` by itself at the class level if you are trying to have all instances of the object have the same value for `a`. Using the `static` modifier means that the value is only initialised once and then shared among objects of the same type, you should also make it `private` unless you want to share the constant with other classes. In your example, each instance of `JustFinal` will initialise `int a=20;` rather than all using the same copy (although the JIT will probably optimise this out for you).

Ultimately you can call `a` and `b` whatever you like, as long as people understand you. But if you used the phrase *"objects constant"* in conversation with me I'd have no idea what you were talking about.

The difference between a *constant* (defined at compile time) and a variable that, once assigned cannot have it's value changed, is *mutability* (not to be confused with [immutable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)).

I'd use the term "immutable property/variable" over "objects constant".

Comment: We know that we can assign a value to a final variable only at 2 places : i) Either we assign it a value at the time of Declaration; OR ii) We assign it a value in a Constructor. If we choose the Option (i) we can't assign it different value for different object. And if choose option (ii) we can have a different value of a final variable for different object. Doesn't the Option (i) makes the final variable a CONSTANT as it have the same value for all the instances of that class?